# I have written a quick sort code and logic seem pretty correct but there is no output on the console

Tags: c++, quicksort

I have written a quick sort code and logic seem pretty correct but there is no output on the console.

when only index function runs the output is correct and also the output loop is correct but when quicSort function is added then there is no output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int index(int* a, int s, int e) {
  int i, j, start, piv, temp;
  start = s;

  piv = a[e];

  for (i = start; i <= e; i++) {
    if (a[i] <= piv) {
      temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[start];
      a[start] = temp;
      start++;
    }
  }

  return start;
}

void quickSort(int* a, int s, int e) {
  int pivot;
  if (s < e) {
    pivot = index(a, s, e);
    quickSort(a, s, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(a, pivot + 1, e);
  }
}

int main() {
  int A[] = {2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 1, 4};
  quickSort(A, 0, 7);

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cout << A[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

the output should be sorted array

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Your program gets stuck in an endless loop. Start with smaller and less arbitrary test cases, like `{1}`, `{1,2}`, `{2,1}`, `{1,1}`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Code needs two fixes. Changes noted in comments:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int index(int* a, int s, int e) {
  int i, start, piv;            // j, temp not used
  start = s;

  piv = a[e];

  for (i = start; i <= e; i++) {
    if (a[i] < piv) {           // fix (not <=)
      swap(a[i], a[start]);     // simplify
      start++;
    }
  }
  swap(a[start], a[e]);         // fix (swap pivot into place)

  return start;
}

void quickSort(int* a, int s, int e) {
  int pivot;
  if (s < e) {
    pivot = index(a, s, e);
    quickSort(a, s, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(a, pivot + 1, e);
  }
}

int main() {
  int A[] = {2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 1, 4};
  quickSort(A, 0, 7);

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cout << A[i] << " ";        // put space beteen numbers
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit, tidy up with a newline (e.g. `cout << '\n';`) so you don't mess up your prompt.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I missed an edit. Answer is updated now (using std::endl instead of "\n").

Comment: There is actually a good article on the use of `'\n'` v. `std::endl`. [ACCU Overload No. 149 - Don't Use std::endl](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - For this case, it's only once at the end of a program, so not a big deal. If I'm doing I/O intensive stuff, I generally use binary file I/O with large buffers without translation (so for DOS/WIndows, it's carriage return / line feed in whatever syntax used by a language), as opposed to stream I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get confused by bubblesort when creating your quicksort program.

The quicksort ideia is to break the vector in smaller vectors one with the numbers bigger than the pivot e another with the numbers smaller than the pivot.

You should round up your code in C++ data structures like vectors.

One example is, with c++11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> quicksort(vector<int> data) {
  if (data.size() == 1) return data;
  vector<int> small_numbers;
  vector<int> big_numbers;
  vector<int> ret;
  float pivot = accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0) / data.size();

  for (int value : data) {
    if (value < pivot) {
      small_numbers.push_back(value);
    } else {
      big_numbers.push_back(value);
    }
  }
  if (small_numbers.empty()) return big_numbers;

  small_numbers = quicksort(small_numbers);
  big_numbers = quicksort(big_numbers);

  ret.insert(ret.end(), small_numbers.begin(), small_numbers.end());
  ret.insert(ret.end(), big_numbers.begin(), big_numbers.end());

  return ret;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> A({2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9, 1, 4});

  A = quicksort(A);

  for (int value : A) cout << value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This example break the the vector into two vectors, the pivot is the mean value of the values of vector. It calls the function recursively until it calls a vector with the size of 1 element.

Hope it push you to a less complicated way of see quicksort.

Comment: thanks @Blastfurnace, i forgot to put a stop if the vector are full of the same values !!